# Get common value from two records in a vue array

Tags: vue.js

I have this record in vue.js data, i want to select both records options and only one of the question since they both have the same question id

```
[
  {
     "id":7,
     "question_id":102,
     "option":"true",
     "is_correct":"1",
     "question":"This is a question",
     "option_type":1
 },
{
     "id":8,
     "question_id":102,
     "option":"false",
     "is_correct":"0",
     "question":"This is a question",
      "option_type":1
}
]
```

**Expected result**
what i'm expecting after the execution of the solution is

```
    question_id:[
        { 
            "id":7,
            "option":"true",
            "is_correct":"1",
            "question":"This is a question",
            "option_type":1
         }
         { 
            "id":8,
            "option":"false",
            "is_correct":"0",
            "question":"This is a question",
            "option_type":1
         }
       ]
```

**What i have tried**

```
   <label class="form-control" v-for="question in response" :key="question.id" track-by="question_id">{{ question.question }}</label>
    <div v-for="option in response" :key="option.id">
    <input type="radio" name="pickedAnswer" id="option" :value="option.id">
    <label for="option" class="ml-3">{{option.option}}</label><br>                                    </div>
```

I will be in the comments thank you

Comment: Can you be more exhaustive ? It looks like you want to do a groupBy the ID key, and create an array with all the questions that have the same id. Is that correct ?

Comment: Yes that’s what I want to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve it with vanilla JS:

```js
let arr = [
  {
     "id":7,
     "question_id":102,
     "option":"true",
     "is_correct":"1",
     "question":"This is a question",
     "option_type":1
  },
  {
     "id":8,
     "question_id":102,
     "option":"false",
     "is_correct":"0",
     "question":"This is a question",
      "option_type":1
  }
]

const groupBy = function(origin, key) {
  return origin.reduce(function(res, element) {
    (res[element[key]] = res[element[key]] || []).push(element);
    delete element[key];
    return res;
  }, {});
};

console.log(groupBy(arr, 'question_id'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you want to achieve, you dont need vue.
Vue v-for and html is used to show data, not transform them. So I suggest you to create a function ( inside the created() hook or mounted(), it depends where your data come from ) and use a groupBy to get all the data.

I know two way to do something like this, use lodash or use native es6. I'll write both

```
 // ES6 

 resp.reduce((acc, value) => {
   acc[value.question_id] = [...acc[value.question_id] || [], value]
 return acc;
}, {});

// { 102: [{ id: 7, ...}, { id: 8, ...}] }
```

You can use a reduce to create a new object with question_id as ID and the grouped question as value

[Lodash](https://lodash.com/)

```
// Lodash

_.groupBy(a, 'question_id')

// { 102: [{ id: 7, ...}, { id: 8, ...}] }
```

Is much simple, but you have to install a lodash library ( and is not really a good idea for one function, lodash is huuuge )
If you want to install lodash,  I suggest you to read this article, that explain the correct way to import lodash without kill you build [The correct way to import lodash](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-correct-way-to-import-lodash-libraries-a-benchmark/)